# Is the TV series The Secret Circle a faithful reproduction of the book series

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-secret-circle

I've been watching *The Secret Circle* recently & was very impressed by it. I found it to be the best among Teen fantasy shows on TV. But it has only 1 season & was cancelled. Wikipedia tells me its based on a book series with the same name.

Before asking the actual question, a little context.
I was a fan of *Pretty Little Liars* & after season 1, picked up the books. But i was mighty disappointed. Although the major plot points were similar, the path connecting them was much much better in the TV series than in the books. A completely different screenplay & episodic script.
I was disappointed by the books & it spoiled the series for me.

So, now i want to delve into *The Secret Circle* books as the TV series as of now remains cancelled.
So, does the books faithfully follow the season 1 of the Secret Circle. If not, what are the discrepancies.?
Also, should I go into reading the books.

**PS**- I know the question is opinionated & the site doesn't favor such stuff. But *The Secret Circle* was not a widely 
popular show. So there cannot be a popular opinion which becomes a fact.
So I am looking for an answer from anybody who has actually read the books

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The books and TV show are very different. I really enjoyed the show when I started watching it on Neftlix over the summer, so I read the book series after I finished the TV series.
In my opinion, they really have very little in common other than the general premise of Cassie Blake discovering that she comes from a secret lineage of witchcraft. Beyond that, the major similarities are just names.
The first thing to be aware of with the books is that the first 3 are written by the original author, and then they had a ghost author pick up the series when the TV show came out, and had her write 3 more for the series. There is a definite shift between the voices of the writers and the nature of the books, and the last three were designed to be more like the TV series, but still has very little in common with them.
But, in terms of how they are different, the book series starts with Cassie and her mother (who is alive throughout the entire series) having to move to New Salem to take care of her aging grandmother. Cassie is bullied by Faye and her friends and can't seem to fit in until she finds out that she is initiated into a Circle. The main plot in the original trilogy is that the spirit of an ancient, evil witch is unleashed, and the Circle has to stop him before he hurts the mortal townsfolk and their Circle. 
There is no boat fire in the book, no witch hunters, or any of the other major plot problems in the TV show.
I liked the TV show much better, and thought that it was written for an older YA demographic--the book series would maybe be more entertaining for pre-teens than teens. To avoid giving spoilers, there isn't as much of the supernatural/thriller/drama genres in the book series as in the TV series. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: This was just the answer i was looking for. I think i'll give the books a miss from your summary of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The differences are as

> - Melanie Glaser, Susan Whittier, Deborah Armstrong, Laurel Quincey, Sean Dulany, Chris Henderson  and Doug Henderson are the characters who don't appear in the TV series but are present in the book.
> - Jake Armstrong (Portrayed by Chris Zylka) and Melissa Glaser (Portrayed by Jessica Parker Kennedy) don't appear in the book. They are fictional characters for the TV series.
> - In the book, Faye is bullying Cassie at school, and in the TV series Faye sets Cassie's car on fire.
> - In the book, Adam and Cassie meet in the summer in Cape Cod. But in the TV series, they haven't met before school starts.
> - In the book, the crystal skull is one whole piece, but in the TV series, the crystal skull is divided into several crystals.
> - The city name is changed from New Salem to Chance Harbor.
> - The TV version of Nick is immature and nothing like the book version.
> - There are 12 witches in the circle in the book, not 6.
> - Diana is much more good and Faye is much more evil in the book.
> - In the book, Cassie's mother is still alive when they move.

(Source: [thatwasnotinthebook.com](http://thatwasnotinthebook.com/diff/secret-circle/1#diffPage))

Comment: Great heads-up on the characters front. Could u also throw some light on the story. I am not asking exact details but whether the episodic story is similar. Whether the differences in situations are minor or completely different because of many more characters. Also your opinion on whether i should read it, if u have read it.

Comment: @KharoBangdo i am unaware of the book and watched TV series in little parts. The whole differences i got is from the link. So, can't help more. May someone come up with more elaborated answer as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you love a good read then you will really enjoy the books. A lot of the major differences are:

- the abandoned house wasn't a house but an empty lot that was the 13th member's house
- they all lived on the same street
- Fay's mom wasn't principal
- each of the kids lost a parent in a fire which was the abandoned house and that's why Cassie's mom took her away
- they changed the city and state to the opposite coast (the books took place in Salem and New Salem on the east coast in New England, not in Washington state)
- Diana had long blonde hair not short brown

There are many differences and my opinion the books are much better.